# Error 010240: Can't save my con statement as a tiff?

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-10.4, geotiff-tiff, error-010240

I want to write a conditional statement and save it as a .tif file. I have looked through the documentation from ArcGIS and as far as I can tell, my code *should* work, but I keep getting an error that the computer can't save what I want as a raster. I have saved .tif files earlier in my code, so I'm not sure what the problem is. I've tried to save in different file formats as well, but I got the same error message.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
from arcpy.sa import * 

path = 'folderlocation'
env.workspace = path  #this is the work environment
template = 'actualrd.tif'
env.extent = template  #set the extent
env.cellSize = template  #set the cell size
env.overwriteOutput = True  #set overwrite output to true

tempEuc = 'temp_dist.tif'
outEucDist = EucDistance(actualrd, 500)
outEucDist.save(tempEuc)

tempCon = r'temp_con.tif'
outCon = Con(((tempEuc >=0) & ('actualrd' == 1)), 1)
outCon.save(tempCon)
```

I can save the euclidean distance raster file, but not the conditional statement raster file.

> RuntimeError: ERROR 010240: Could not save raster dataset to [file
>   location] with output format TIFF.

I am using ArcGIS 10.4.1

Comment: Please edit the question to specify the version of ArcGIS in use.

Comment: I wrote something very similar the other day, and it worked fine. You have genericized the code block to hide your actual code, and I suspect that has masked the issue. As presented here, this code should return Python errors, not ArcPy ones. Please it the question to be an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Vince I added more information, not sure if that helps... Maybe it would help to know that I am trying to run this code in a loop, but even outside of the loop, this code doesn't work.

Comment: The `'actualrd' == 1` statement doesn't make sense. You are comparing a string to an integer. Shouldn't this be `Raster('actualrd') == 1`?

Comment: Your folder location is possibly the problem. What is the actual path? If you're trying to save to a GDB you'll get that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure your output path is correct (i.e. you can't save tiffs to a GDB).
- You have a number of errors in your code, try the following:

```python
actualrd = Raster('actualrd.tif') #Make template a Raster object
env.extent = actualrd  #set the extent
env.cellSize = actualrd  #set the cell size
env.overwriteOutput = True  #set overwrite output to true

tempEuc = 'temp_dist.tif'
outEucDist = EucDistance(actualrd, 500)
outEucDist.save(tempEuc)

tempCon = r'temp_con.tif'
outCon = Con(((outEucDist >=0) & (actualrd == 1)), 1) #use outEucDist not tempEuc and actualrd Raster object not 'actualrd' string

outCon.save(tempCon)
```

Comment: Wow thank you! That worked! Do you know why putting the raster file name (instead of outEucDistance) in the conditional statement not work?

Comment: Because you need to use a raster in the expression not a string. The file name is not a raster to arcpy, it is a string.